# ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase) method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

How to change the default Action name inside the ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase) method..

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743361/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-routing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish... on which class is the ProcessRequest method you're referring to defined?  Why do you want to change the action name? (and why does the [ActionNameAttribute](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/11/19/asp-net-mvc-actionnameattribute-and-actionmethodselector-class.aspx) not suffice?)